# Update Slider position CPU Load Javafx

Tags: java, performance, javafx

Good day,

I try to level my JavaFx skills and I am programming a little media player.
Hence, there is a slider object which will be responsible to show the user the elapsed time (and seek the track position if the user wants to).

To monitor the current track position I use another thread  which will ask for the elapsed time each 100 ms. It updates a DoubleProperty, which the slidervalue will be binded to.
This works, however CPU usage increases to 70-80 % if I do so.

Snippet:

```
 Task task = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override public Void call() throws InterruptedException {
            double time=0;
            double dummy=0;
            while(true) {
                try{
                      if(time == tmp.getPlaytime()){
                            dummy += 0.1;
                      }else{
                     dummy = time;
                     }
                    updateProgress(dummy, tracklength.getValue());
                    time = tmp.getPlaytime();
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    };
    trackposition.bind(task.progressProperty());
    new Thread(task).start();
```

tmp is the object which will provide the elapsed time, and the method can raise an exception, hence the try/catch block.
tracklength is a DoubleProperty which provides the Length of the track in seconds.
Since I only have a time resolution of a second within the method in tmp I use the dummy variable to make a smooth slider animation.
The idea for this thread - approach, was taken from [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm)

I know that multithreading and GUI is a difficult topic, but do you have any idea how drop the CPU usage ? 
(Will the runLater() approach work better in your opinion ? Since runLater means I have no idea when it will be executed, I can not provide a "smooth" transition and wouldn't "want" to use it then )

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've created this short sample to test your task, and it's working flawlessly, no relevant CPU usage.

```
private volatile boolean running = true;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    final Media song = new Media(<Media URL>);
    MediaPlayer  media_player = new MediaPlayer(song);

    Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override 
        public Void call() throws InterruptedException {
            double time=0;
            double dummy=0;
            while(running) {
                try{
                    if(time == media_player.getCurrentTime().toSeconds()){
                        dummy += 0.1;
                    }else{
                        dummy = time;
                    }
                    updateProgress(dummy, media_player.getTotalDuration().toSeconds());
                    time = media_player.getCurrentTime().toSeconds();
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    running=false;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    };

    Slider slider = new Slider(0,100,0);    
    slider.valueProperty().bind(task.progressProperty().multiply(100));

    media_player.setOnReady(() -> {
        new Thread(task).start();
        media_player.play();
    });

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(slider);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Try to run it, and check if it works, and how is the CPU usage.